# Can't pair JBL Flip 3 to MacBook Pro 13" running macOS 10.12.5

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, speakers

My JBL Flip 3 won't connect to my 13" MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Here's what I do:

I open my Bluetooth preferences on my MBP and power up the Flip 3 into pairing mode (power light changes to flashing blue). My MBP sees the "JBL Flip 3" and displays a <kbd>Pair</kbd> button. I click on this and "connecting..." displays.

However, a spinning wheel appears to the right and spins forever and the Flip 3 power light continues to flash.

Nothing else is listed in the MBP Bluetooth list. Nothing else is paired to the Flip 3. I've tried all kinds of combinations with no success.

What else can I try?

Comment: Have you contacted JBL tech support to ask for help?  There might be a problem with your Flip 3.  Have you connected any other BT device to your MBP?

Comment: MacOS Mojave this works - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7850133

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved here as well.

Answer (score 8):

First of all I would check with [JBL Support](https://www.jbl.com/support-knowledgebase.html) for any known issues, updates, compatibility, etc.

On the MBP side of things you could try resetting both the macOS Bluetooth Device List and Bluetooth Controller and pairing your JBL Flip 3 first. However, this will reset **all** connected Bluetooth devices, including a keyboard and mouse.

**In other words, this will remove all existing pairing information for Bluetooth devices, so each will need to be reconnected.**

I have some steps you can follow, but I strongly suggest you read all of the steps first before commencing (or perhaps print out the instructions / view them on another device).

Before starting, ensure you have the Bluetooth icon showing in the menu bar. If it is not there, open System Preferences > Bluetooth and enable the option *Show Bluetooth in Menu Bar*.

Once done, follow these steps:

1. Hold down both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys and at the same time click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar. Once the menu is showing, release the keys.
2. From the Bluetooth menu, choose Debug > Remove All Devices
3. Hold down both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys again and at the same time click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar.
4. From the Bluetooth menu,  choose Debug > Reset the Bluetooth Module
5. Shutdown your Mac
6. Ensure your JBL Flip 3 is fully powered **off**
7. Restart your Mac
8. On your Mac, click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar
9. Select the *Set Up Bluetooth Device* option
10. Now ensure your JBL Flip 3 is in pairing mode (i.e. press the power button for at least 3 seconds until you see the blue flashing light)
11. Once the Setup Assistant finds the Flip 3, select it from the list and click on “Continue”.
12. Now pair your speaker
13. If you have any other Bluetooth devices, you can go ahead and pair them now (or you can do it later). However, the point is to pair the JBL Flip 3 first before any other Bluetooth devices!

Comment: Thank you. Resetting bluetooth on my mac solved my same problem!

Comment: It did not work for me on mac os 10.13.4 (High Sierra). But the method described in https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7850133 worked!

Comment: @deps_stats FTW

Answer (score 1):

Try open JBL Connect and turn on this:

[image]

Then connect to the MacBook

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with JBL Tune 230NC TWS earbuds trying to connect to a MacBook after previously having them connected to my iPhone.

I disconnected the earbuds from my iPhone (obviously). My MacBook paired with other devices without problem.

The solution I found was to COMPLETELY POWER-OFF my iPhone. Then I was able to pair with the MacBook Air successfully and normally.Then after powering-on the iPhone (and disconnecting the earbuds from the MacBook - don't delete the device, just toggle it off from the Bluetooth dropdown), I could re-pair from my iPhone normally.

After that it was a simple matter to toggle between MacBook and iPhone:

1. open the JBL pulse box. It will pair with whichever device it was last paired with.
2. Disconnect it. It will go back into pairing mode.
3. Select it from the other device.

Comment: This worked for me. Same earbuds JBL TUNE230NC TWS. I had to power off both my iPhone and iPad which I had previously connected with the earbuds.

Answer (score -1):

This solved the issue for me. Thanks to Deps_stats for posting this!
discussions.apple.com/thread/7850133

This is so silly..

Follow these steps:

1. Start from the beginning. Remove the speaker from the Bluetooth devices list.
2. Power on JBL device.
3. Actually HOLD down the Bluetooth button on the JBL device for 3 seconds before you try paring.
4. PAIR.

Now it works for me and it shows up in my sound options.

The only thing different I did when it didn't work was that I didn't HOLD down the bluetooth on the JBL device. I only pressed it once... so redonkeylous!